# Cannot infer type for generic

Tags: rust

I am having some confusion with generics and bounds and would appreciate some clarity on this.

I have a struct that requires a generic paramter.

```rust
pub struct DataState<P : JsonRpcClient> {
    pub path: Sudo<SignerMiddleware<Provider<Provider<P>>, Bastion<SigningKey>>>,
    pub wrapper: Wrapper<SignerMiddleware<Provider<Provider<P>>, Bastion<SigningKey>>>,
    // pub rpc_url: String,
    // pub key: String,
    pub provder: Arc<SignerMiddleware<Provider<Http>, Bastion<SigningKey>>>,
}
```

```
#[post("/process")]
async fn process<P : JsonRpcClient>(field: web::Json<Region>, data: web::Data<DataState<P>>) -> impl Responder
// where P: JsonRpcClient
{
```

However , I get this error

```
|
126 | async fn process<P : JsonRpcClient>(field: web::Json<Region>, data: web::Data<DataState<P>>) -> impl Responder
    |          ^^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `P` declared on the function `process`
```

Comment: Rocket doesn't support generic type parameters on route functions.

Comment: It isn’t rocket it’s actix

Comment: I think the same thing applies to Actix.

Comment: Thanks where is this documented so as to help my learning?

Comment: I don't think it's documented _to_ work. Here's a thought experiment for you: since generics are supplied by the caller of a function, where do you think the `P` type argument can come from in response to an incoming HTTP request?